# Issue with tarfile and invalid header error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tarfile

I have a tarfile from http://download.geofabrik.de/africa/botswana-latest.osm.bz2

When I save the file to disk and use the Python [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) library to extract the .osm file, I get an invalid header error.

Is there a way around this error?

7zip can open the file and extract the data without an issue but I need to script the extraction of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats not a tarfile!  It's a flat file compressed with bzip2.  You can use the [python bz2 standard module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html) to interact with files that are compressed with bzip2.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy!